# Computation of the limit of $\frac{1}{A} \int_{1}^{A} A^{1/x} \,dx$ as $A\to \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

Compute the limit (if there is one) of

$$ \frac{1}{A} \int_{1}^{A} A^{1/x}\, dx $$

as $A \to \infty$.

--

I actually managed to solve it, and although I know the policy of MathSE, I found it so nice I wanted to share this with you guys (this is also the purpose of this forum to share interesting problems) : enjoy ! For those interested, many more similar questions may be found here https://www.ens.fr/sites/default/files/2019_mathsulm_sujets-1.pdf

--

As mentioned by @zhw in the comments, the question has already been raised at least three times in this forum:

[How to compute: $ \lim\limits_{a\to \infty}\frac1a\int_1^a a^{\frac1x} dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2499739/how-to-compute-lim-limits-a-to-infty-frac1a-int-1a-a-frac1x-dx/2503219#2503219)

[Computing $\lim_{A\to\infty} \frac{1}{A} \int\limits_1^A \! A^{\frac{1}{x}} \, \mathrm{d}x.$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1424234/computing-lim-a-to-infty-frac1a-int-limits-1a-a-frac1x)

[Problem 7 IMC 2015 - Integral and Limit](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1382003/problem-7-imc-2015-integral-and-limit)

Beware the accepted answer to the first of these questions is formally wrong (no domination). Among these solutions, the quicker ones are the one that perform a change of variable, $A^{1/x}= A^{y}$ or $A^{1/x}=e^z$, and the one below. One may also dispense from the use of L'Hopital rule.

--

To be complete, let me add this question seems to be due to Jan Sustek, University of Ostrava, and that the solution sheet for the contest they come from (ICM 2015) is to be found [here](http://www.imc-math.org.uk/imc2015/imc2015-day2-solutions.pdf)

Comment: I bet for $1$. I shall put an answer tomorrow.

Comment: This problem has certainly appeared at MSE before; in fact I think I posted an answer to it.

Comment: Found it: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2499739/how-to-compute-lim-limits-a-to-infty-frac1a-int-1a-a-frac1x-dx/2503219#2503219

Comment: @zhw Nice ! Now, I really have a lot of solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [L'Hospital's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule) and [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule) to get
$$
\lim_{A \to \infty} \frac{1}{A} \int_{1}^{A} A^{1/x} dx = \lim_{A \to \infty} \big(A^{1/A} + \frac{1}{A}\int_{1}^A \frac{A^{1/x}}{x} dx \big) = 1 + \lim_{A \to \infty} \frac{1}{A}\int_{1}^A \frac{A^{1/x}}{x} dx
$$

In order to compute obtained integral use the same technique once again:
$$
\lim_{A \to \infty} \frac{1}{A}\int_{1}^A \frac{A^{1/x}}{x} dx = \lim_{A \to \infty}  \big( \frac{A^{1/A}}{A} + \frac{1}{A}\int_{1}^A \frac{A^{1/x}}{x^2} dx\big) = \lim_{A \to \infty} \frac{1}{A}\int_{1}^A \frac{A^{1/x}}{x^2} dx
$$

Now the last integral can be evaluated directly with substitution $t = 1/x$. Once it's calculated, we establish
$$
\lim_{A \to \infty} \frac{1}{A}\int_{1}^A \frac{A^{1/x}}{x^2} dx = 0,
$$
and the answer to the problem is
$$
\lim_{A \to \infty} \frac{1}{A} \int_{1}^{A} A^{1/x} dx = 1.
$$

Comment: I'd love if you included the substitution in the answer for others clarity.

Comment: Also, first line is an IBP with some missing $\log(A)$ terms, no?

Comment: @Olivier what is IBP?

Comment: @Jakobian I suppose it's more like a homework question, so I left it as a simple exercise

Comment: @Virtuoz IBP = Integration By Part. I don't get the use of L'Hopital and Leibniz here.

Comment: @Olivier there is no integration by parts in the first line. I apply L'Hospital's rule to the fraction $\frac{\int_1^A A^{1/x} dx}{A}$ and then differentiate the numerator according to the Leibniz rule.

Comment: You get a similar but not identical argument if you use IBP.

Comment: Yep. Got it. Would that method also give second order term of the asymptotic expansion of $\int_1^A A^{1/x} dx$ ?

Comment: This method just shows that $\int_1^A A^{1/x} dx = A(1 + o(1))$ when $A \to \infty$. It seems to me that it's the only information we can get using this method. I think one can get an asymptotic expansion of $f(A) = \int_1^A A^{1/x} dx$, considering Taylor expansion of $g(A) = f(1/A)$ at zero point.

Comment: I did it myself using a change of variable $e^z = A^{1/x}$ and then studying the behaviour of the resulting ($A$-free) integrand at the two ($A$-dependent) bounds;  in this way, the asymptotic expansion comes quite easily, hence my question about this method... Interesting anyway !

Answer (score 1):

I think that we can obtain more than the limit itself.
$$\int A^{\frac{1}{x}}  dx=x A^{\frac{1}{x}}-\log (A) \text{Ei}\left(\frac{\log (A)}{x}\right)$$
$$\int_1^A A^{\frac{1}{x}}  dx=A^{\frac{1}{A}+1}+\log (A) \text{Ei}(\log (A))-\log (A) \text{Ei}\left(\frac{\log(A)}{A}\right)-A$$
and use 
$$\text{Ei}(t)=\gamma+\log (t) +t+\frac{t^2}{4}+O\left(t^3\right)$$
$$\text{Ei}(t)=e^t
   \left(\frac{1}{t}+\frac{1}{t^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{t^3}\right)\right)$$ 
which make
$$\int_1^A A^{\frac{1}{x}}  dx\sim A^{\frac{1}{A}+1}-\frac{\log ^3(A)}{4 A^2}-\frac{\log ^2(A)}{A}+\frac{A}{\log
   (A)}-\log (A) \left(\log \left(\frac{\log (A)}{A}\right)+\gamma \right)+\cdots$$
$$\frac 1 A \int_1^A A^{\frac{1}{x}}  dx\sim A^{\frac{1}{A}}-\frac{\log ^3(A)}{4 A^3}-\frac{\log ^2(A)}{A^2}+\frac{1}{\log
   (A)}-\frac{\log (A)}A \left(\log \left(\frac{\log (A)}{A}\right)+\gamma \right)+\cdots$$

Comment: Nice ! So two IBP's right ?  Doing the change of variable A^{1/x}=e^z also gives access to the asymptotic expansion but I have not been to that order :-)

Comment: @Olivier. The change of variable does not make any difference; we end with the same formula. Just out of curioisity : are you at *Gnouf* ?

Comment: Quite relieved that the change of variable does not change the asymptotics ;-))).  And no, no gnouf there, but I happen to know the examinator this year.